# can't write .bashrc to add path of android NDK

Tags: android, bash, android-ndk

I have downloaded NDK for my eclips juno....now i have to add the NDK to path and have to add lines to .bashrc.

I have to add the following lines to my .bashrc

```
export ANDROID_NDK=/_path_to/android-ndk-linux/
export ANDROID_SDK=/_path_to/android-sdk-linux/
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK/tools:$ANDROID_SDK/platform-tools:$ANDROID_NDK
```

In my terminal I wrote....

```
 ~/.bashrc
```

But it says bash:

```
/home/user/.bashrc: Permission denied
```

how can I change permission to write to .bashrc?????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you type on the command line:

```
~/.bashrc
```

You are requesting that the shell execute the file.  If you want to edit the file, try:

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

Replace `nano` with the name of your favorite editor.

If you just want to copy and paste those three lines into your file, you don't really need an editor.  Just run the following:

```
cat >>~/.bashrc
```

Then, copy and paste those three lines.  Then press enter and type control-D and you are done.